# Deploying a Click-Once Application

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I am trying to deploy my application to be downloaded from my website. It is written in .NET 4.0. I think I have it on my server but I am not sure? When I try to deploy it again I receive this message.

[image: Already Exists]

Here is the setting I have for publishing.

[image: settings1]
[image: settings2]

And as you can see from the website, nothing is there.

[image: website]

Im not the best with web stuff, so my question is what the heck am i missing.

More Info
So. I published it to the wrong location, but i found it.
[image: WrongPublishLocation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your folder http://www.theinsanityelement.com/insanepin/download/ is empty. You have entered ftp://neshmet.dreamhost.com/ as target location - I guess this is mapped to http://www.theinsanityelement.com/ root. That means you should enter

```
ftp://neshmet.dreamhost.com/insanepin/download/
```

as publish folder location, or whatever path is mapped to your target URL. Then you can access the download page from

```
http://www.theinsanityelement.com/insanepin/download/publish.htm
```

You could also change the "Deployment Web Page" name to `index.htm`, then the following would also work:

```
http://www.theinsanityelement.com/insanepin/download/
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution now Frank, hope your still around when i run into another problem. Thanks already, you got me farther than I was

Comment: Please add more screenshots. What does happen when you click "Publish now"? What is shown in the Output pane of Visual Studio?

Comment: And where did it publish it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67814/discussion-between-calvin-smith-and-frank).

Comment: Frank was able to fix my problem in chat. a problem with dreamhsot users only having access to 1 domain